# Found a string in text. Need to print until next space

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need your kind suggestion on how it is possible to load the value following the string into a variable using the find method.
I searched for a line contained in a text file that has a fixed format ("lea=") while the next value that I wish to save has a variable length instead.
As I did in the code below, sometimes it doesn't work perfectly if the value after my search criteria has fewer or even more digits than expected.
My need is to save in the res variable all digits until the first empty space in text line

In the case that value after the string "lea=" in the text line has a right length the value I set in the variable res is ok. In all other case res does not get the right value.
I wish to save all digits after "lea=" until next empty space

Thanks a lot in advance

My text file:

```
icd icd=3/23 lea=Test_12345 status=I start=202307040837 stop=202307040841 fileref=9661234567 mtime=202307040841 doo=20230704
icd icd=6/23 lea=Test_123456789 status=I start=202307040837 stop=202307040841 fileref=9661234567 mtime=202307040841 doo=20230704
icd icd=9/23 lea=Test_1 status=I start=202307040837 stop=202307040841 fileref=9661234567 mtime=202307040841 doo=20230704

line1 ok
line2 notOk
line3 notOk
```

Python 2.7.5 (default, Sep 26 2019, 13:23:47)

```
def getLea(icd):
    f = open("icds.txt")
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    x=0
    while x < len(lines):
        r=lines[x].find("lea=")
        line=lines[x]
        if r != -1:
            res=str(line[r+4:r+12])
            return res
        x +=1
```

Comment: you really shouldn't be using Python 2

Comment: This is the python version installed by default on a production server. Not possible to upgrade

Comment: What is the `icd` parameter in `getLea`? What is it for?

Comment: @AntonioNovi you should read up on Python virtual environments. Some Linux distros still ship with Python2, but you should never write new code for Python2.

Comment: Python 3 has been dead (unsupported) for over 3 years. It was announced 10 years before that date. Do you really work for a company that hasn't managed to get a handle on this in over 13 years?

Comment: Python on the production server is only used to generate some data as input to another application installed on the same machine. For security reasons no network connected and no updates possible except packages to fix bugs and security patches. Anyway Thanks a lot Barmar. It works

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` to split the line into words. Loop over the words in the line, and check if it starts with `lea=`. If it does, return the word.

```
def getLea(icd):
    with open("icds.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            for word in line.split():
                if word.startswith("lea=")
                    return word[4:]
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Barmar solution, you can use regular expression to accomplish the same objective:

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import re


def getLea(icd):
    with open(icd) as stream:
        contents = stream.read()

    found = re.findall(r"lea=(\w+)", contents)
    return found


found = getLea("icds.txt")
print(found)
```

Output:

```
['Test_12345', 'Test_123456789', 'Test_1']
```

#### Notes

- I assume the parameter `icd` points to a file name
- Explanation for the regular expression:

  - The `lea=` part is easy: it literally matches the string "lea="
  - The parentheses ( and ) creates a group and `.findall` will return everything found in this group
  - Within the group, the `\w+` part defines any word, excluding spaces

Comment: Since it's always followed by a number, you could use `\d+` instead of `\w+`